# Java Build Nested HashMap from Objects Fields

Tags: java, parsing, nested

I am new to Java and I have following problem.

I have an Object from which I extract two Objects: MetaData and NestedObject.
NestedObject is an Iterable of "n" Objects (let's call them Inners). 
Each of Inners is an instance of same class so it has same fields with some values.

so, let's say MetaData has fields getA(), getB(), getX() and each fields returns some value A, B, X.

Similarly, Inners have fields getG(), getH(),..., getN() such that these methods return

```
-> G1, H1, N1; for Inner1;
-> G2, H2, N2; for Inner2;
-> GN, HN, NN; for InnerN;
```

What I want to create is a Collection so I have HashMap such that:

```
{
"metadata": [A,B,X],
"inners": [[G1, H1,...N1], [G2, H2,...N2], ... [GN,HN,...,NN]]
}
```

I was thinking about creating some kind of Pojo class to extract field values and build HashMaps but I am not sure what direction to look for.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a set of POJOs, for example (without Map):

```
class MyObject {
    private Metadata metadata;
    private List<Inners> nestedObject;
// getters/setters
}

class Metadata {
    private String a;
    private int b;
// other fields, getters/setters
}

class Inners {
    private String g;
    private Date h;
    private int n;
// other fields, getters/setters
}
```